# Preventing recursion when calling a builtin inside a shell function

Tags: bash, shell, cd

I added below function in bashrc :-

```
function cd(){
        echo "user switching to" $1
        cd $1
}
```

after reloading .bashrc, attempt to cd in temp directory (any directory) gives below recursive error :-

```
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
bash: echo: write error: Bad address
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
user switching to temp/
```

I want the method name to be cd, as i want to execute some logic, whenever user uses cd command.

Comment: FYI, the `function` keyword is nonstandard, and restricts your code's portability. To work with all POSIX shells, remove it and just define your function starting with `cd() {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `builtin` command in bash :

```
function cd(){
        echo "user switching to $1"
        builtin cd "$@"
}
```

Comment: `cd` takes a limited number of options as well; `$1` is not necessarily the name of the new working directory.

Comment: `builtin cd "$@"` would be more robust.